# Android - How to download a file from a webserver

Tags: android, webserver, kml

In my app I am downloading a `kml` file from a webserver. I have set the permission for external storage and internet in my android manifest file. I am new to Android, your help is greatly appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadFiles();
    }

    public void DownloadFiles(){
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://www.qwikisoft.com/demo/ashade/20001.kml");
            InputStream is = u.openStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "data/test.kml"));
            while ((length = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest File**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Logcat error:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:71)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>       at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>       at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
>       at com.example.demo.MainActivity.DownloadFiles(MainActivity.java:30)
>       at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

**EDIT**

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute("http://www.qwikisoft.com/demo/ashade/20001.kml");
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         **/
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/data/downloadedfile.kml");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         **/
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code in the emulator the code still does not work - the file is not getting downloaded.

Comment: Do NOT perform network related operation on main thread. Create a separate thread for downloading the file.

Comment: do you mean async task?

Comment: You do not need to call `conection.connect()` before `conection.getContentLength()`, since it is called implicitly by `conection.getContentLength()`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Using [Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

call when you want to download file : `new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    // File url to download
    private static String file_url = "http://www.qwikisoft.com/demo/ashade/20001.kml";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);

    }

    /**
     * Showing Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to download file
     * */
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/2011.kml");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        }

    }
}
```

if not working in 4.0 then add:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Comment: hey i have put the code above ..please check ..the file is not downloaded still...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27388/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-iam4fun)

Comment: This example has a problem. When the codes run at line where getContentLength() a request will be sent with url and then later again at line of url.openStream().

Comment: how about `while (!isCancelled() && (count = input.read(data)) != -1)`

Comment: Why input size is 8192?

Comment: Thanks you for making this answer, but it i insane that something so common takes so much code.

Answer (score 72):

Simple kotlin version

```
fun download(link: String, path: String) {
    URL(link).openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

> is there anyway to get the download progress or downloaded size from this method ?

This is the same realization as defined in `InputStream.copyTo`, but with progress

```
/*inline*/ fun download(link: String, path: String, progress: ((Long, Long) -> Unit)? = null): Long {
    val url = URL(link)
    val connection = url.openConnection()
    connection.connect()
    val length = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) connection.contentLengthLong else
        connection.contentLength.toLong()
    url.openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            var bytesCopied = 0L
            while (bytesRead >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                bytesCopied += bytesRead
                progress?.invoke(bytesCopied, length)
                bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            }
            return bytesCopied
        }
    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
val handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        // length may be negative because it is based on http header
        val (progress, length) = msg.obj as Pair<Long, Long>
    }
}

// call this outside of main thread
val totalSize = download("http://example.site/path/to/file", "path/to/file") { progress, length ->
    // handling the result on main thread
    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(0, progress to length))
}
```

Comment: One more time, kotlin makes simple what should be simple. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for this simple approach ! is there anyway to get the download progress or downloaded size from this method ?

Comment: @JordanH it's depend on how you are using this function

Answer (score 50):

I would recommend using Android [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager)

```java
DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/myfile.mp3");

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setTitle("My File");
request.setDescription("Downloading");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://" + folderName + "/myfile.mp3"));

downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: I've found that the DownloadManager can be horribly slow on slow phones! For example, my latest investigation shows that it took 600ms just to get the filesize, then it sat idle for 5400ms, then it downloaded a 2MB file in 700ms. I would advise to use a proper download manager, instead of Google's.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I totally agree, I switched to the fetch2 library a long time ago (it's pretty fast and solid), but DownloadManager is the more standard and long term answer I could give.

Answer (score 15):

Download File Usind Download Manager

```
    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/content/books/ebooks/game-of-life.pdf");

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setTitle("My File");
    request.setDescription("Downloading");//request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"game-of-life");
    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: This worked. but it copied the file in the public space. Can we copy it to app internal memory like assets. thanks

Comment: in short : You can't make change in 'raw' or 'assets' folder once apk is build.

Comment: Thanks. I am using API 30. How can I create a directory in public space and then download the file there. Thanks

Comment: You can use the **Scope Storage**

Answer (score 12):

It is bad practice to perform network operations on the main thread, which is why you are seeing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. It is prevented by the policy. If you really must do it for testing, put the following in your OnCreate:

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Please remember that is is very bad practice to do this, and should ideally move your network code to an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`.

Answer (score 7):

Mr.Iam4fun your code answer here..You will use thread...

```
   findViewById(R.id.download).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    DownloadFiles();
                }
            }).start();
```

And,then..

```
 public void DownloadFiles(){

        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://www.qwikisoft.com/demo/ashade/20001.kml");
            InputStream is = u.openStream();

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "data/test.kml"));
            while ((length = dis.read(buffer))>0) {
              fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

          } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
          } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
          }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `AsyncTask` and

put your download file code in `doinbackground` of it..

android don't allow anymore to do heavy tasks on main thread to avoid ANR(Application not responding) error

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AsyncTask (or other way to perform a network operation on background).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //create and execute the download task
    MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask();
    async.execute();

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    //execute on background (out of the UI thread)
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        DownloadFiles();
    }

}
```

More info about AsyncTask on [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run these codes in thread or AsyncTask. In order to avoid duplicated callings of same _url(one time for getContentLength(), one time of openStream()), use IOUtils.toByteArray of Apache.

```
void downloadFile(String _url, String _name) {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(_url);
        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
        byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
        FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using AsyncTask you can put the operation in runnable-

```
Runnable r=new Runnable()
{

public void run()
{
///-------network operation code
}
};

//--------call r in this way--
Thread t=new Thread(r);`enter code here`
t.start();

Also put the UI work in a handler..such as updating a textview etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code help you to download file from server at the same time you can see the progress of downloading on your status bar.**

**See the functionality in below image of my code:**

[image] 
[image]

**STEP - 1 :** Create on **DownloadFileFromURL.java** class file to download file content from server. Here i  create an asynchronous task to download file.

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder build;
private File fileurl;
int id = 123;
OutputStream output;
private Context context;
private String selectedDate;
private String ts = "";

public DownloadFileFromURL(Context context, String selectedDate) {
    this.context = context;
    this.selectedDate = selectedDate;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    build = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    build.setContentTitle("Download")
            .setContentText("Download in progress")
            .setChannelId(id + "")
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setDefaults(0)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_download);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id + "",
                "Social Media Downloader",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("no sound");
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        channel.enableLights(false);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        channel.enableVibration(false);
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
    build.setProgress(100, 0, false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
    String msg = "Download started";
    //CustomToast.showToast(context,msg);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    ts = selectedDate.split("T")[0];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                8192);
        // Output stream
        output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + Const.DownloadPath + ts + ".pdf");
        fileurl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + Const.DownloadPath + ts + ".pdf");
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            int cur = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);

            publishProgress(Math.min(cur, 100));
            if (Math.min(cur, 100) > 98) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("Failure", "sleeping failure");
                }
            }
            Log.i("currentProgress", "currentProgress: " + Math.min(cur, 100) + "\n " + cur);

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();

        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    build.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    build.setContentText("Download complete");
    build.setProgress(0, 0, false);
    mNotifyManager.notify(id, build.build());
} }
```

**Note:** If you want code with import package then [Click Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PcnDmdCm8B/)

**Now Step 2:** You need to call above ayncronous task on your click event. for example i have set on pdf image icon.
 To call AsyncTask use below code:

```
 new DownloadFileFromURL(fContext,filename).execute(serverFileUrl);
```

**Note:** Here You can see **filename** variable in file parameter. This is the name which i use to save  my downloaded file in local device. currently i am downloading only pdf file but you can use you url in **serverFileUrl** parameter.

Comment: This looks like the DIY version of download manager..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I download using retrofit, save and return a file to the viewmodel :)

interface FileDownloader {
companion object {
private val instance: FileDownloader by lazy {

```
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()

        val downloaderApi = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://exmaple.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
            .create(FileDownloader::class.java)

        downloaderApi
    }

    suspend fun downloadAndSaveFile(
        url: String
    ): File {
        val file = getPdfFile()
        val responseBody = try {
            instance.downloadFile(url)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw FileDownloadException(url, e)
        }
        @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).use { outputStream ->
                responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw FileDownloadException(url, e)
        }
        return file
    }


}

@GET
@Streaming
suspend fun downloadFile(@Url utl: String): ResponseBody
}

fun getPdfFile(): File {
    File(App.appContext.filesDir, "pdfs").apply { mkdirs() }
    return File(App.appContext.filesDir, "tempPDF.pdf")
}

class FileDownloadException(url: String, e: Exception) : Throwable()
```

Answer (score 0):

all answer is really have write to many code and not clean my best answer is:

binding.btnDownloadPdf.setOnClickListener(view -> {

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(YOUR_URL);
        startActivity(intent);
        
    });
```

Or you Can use library for download:

PRDownloader

link:

https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Vlad's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900037/851699), here is a non-blocking and fairly simple version in kotlin that allows you to provide a callback so you can access the file on download completion (or error):

```
/** Start downloading to the given local path, and call the completionCallback with the local file when done. */
fun startDownload(link: String, path: String, completionCallback: (Result<File>) -> Unit) {
    thread {
        val outputFile = File(path)
        try {
            URL(link).openStream().use { input ->
                FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        } catch (err: Exception) {
            completionCallback(Result.failure(err))
            return@thread
        }
        completionCallback(Result.success(outputFile))
    }
}
```

Example use (from activity):

```
startDownload(
    link = getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.resolve("my_file.json").path,
    path = "https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA",
) { result: Result<File> ->
    result.getOrNull()?.let {
        println("Got file: ${result.getOrNull()?.absolutePath}")
        localModels = reloadLocalModels()
        updateModelListDisplay()
    } ?: println(result.exceptionOrNull()?.toString() ?: "Error with no message")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from api level 11 or Honeycomb doing network operations on main thread is forbidden. Use thread or asynctask. For more info visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score -1):

When you click on download button, first you have to create local storage path where you want to save it, we should put download file functionality into ExecutorService(that is used instead of AsyncTask because AsyncTask is deprecated).

```
// Create bamchik folder if not created yet
val folder = File(context?.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absoluteFile, "MusicTrack")
val check = folder.mkdirs()
Log.v(mTAG, "check: $check")
var path = context?.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + "/MusicTrack/music." + fileExt
val SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
if (SDK_INT > 8) {
    val policy: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
    val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    val handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            // Length is the total size of file and progress is how much file have been downloaded, now you can show progress according to this
            val (progress, length) = msg.obj as Pair<Long, Long> 
            Log.v(mTAG, "Progress: $progress, Length: $length")
        }

    }

    executor.execute {
        //Background work here
        download(link, path) { progress, length ->
            // handling the result on main thread
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(0, progress to length))
        }
        handler.post {
            //UI Thread work here
        }
    }
}
```

Function of download file from url

```
fun download(link: String, path: String, progress: ((Long, Long) -> Unit)? = null): Long {
    val url = URL(link)
    val connection = url.openConnection()
    connection.connect()
    val length = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) connection.contentLengthLong else connection.contentLength.toLong()
    url.openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            var bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            var bytesCopied = 0L
            while (bytesRead >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                bytesCopied += bytesRead
                progress?.invoke(bytesCopied, length)
                bytesRead = input.read(buffer)
            }

            return bytesCopied
        }
    }
}
```