# Get time (& network speed) to download a file in AsyncTask - Android

Tags: android, performance, time, download

I'm newbie in Android.

Can anyone say, how to display in Android UI, during download progressing state, the speed at which a file (say `xyz.mp4`) is downloading and remaining time to complete download the `xyz.mp4` file.

I am using `AsyncTask` for download task, and I want to display speed and time along with "Progress Percentage". I'm using `ProgressDialog` in `DialogFragment`.

**Solution**

```
class DownloadVideoFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Do your pre executing codes (UI part)...
        // The ProgressDialog initializations...
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(params.length < 2)   return "";

        String videoUrlStr = params[0];
        String fileName = params[1];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(videoUrlStr);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // This will be useful so that you can show a 0-100% progress bar
            int fileSizeInB = conection.getContentLength();

            // Download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8 * 1024); // 8KB Buffer
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int bufferSizeInB = 1024;
            byte byteBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSizeInB];
            int bytesRead;

            long bytesInInterval = 0;
            int timeLimit = 500;    // ms.
            long timeElapsed = 0;   // ms.
            long nlwSpeed = 0;      String nlwSpeedStr = null;

            long availableB = 0;
            long remainingBytes = fileSizeInB;
            long remainingTime = 0; String remainingTimeStr = null;

            long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {    // wait to download bytes...
                // bytesRead => bytes already Red
                output.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                availableB += bytesRead;
                bytesInInterval += bytesRead;
                remainingBytes -= bytesRead;

                timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime;
                if(timeElapsed >= timeLimit) {
                    nlwSpeed = bytesInInterval*1000 / timeElapsed;  // In Bytes per sec
                    nlwSpeedStr = nlwSpeed + " Bytes/sec";

                    remainingTime = (long)Math.ceil( ((double)remainingBytes / nlwSpeed) ); // In sec
                    remainingTimeStr = remainingTime + " seconds remaining";

                    // Resetting for calculating nlwSpeed of next time interval
                    timeElapsed = 0;
                    bytesInInterval = 0;
                    startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
                }
                publishProgress(
                        "" + availableB,    // == String.valueOf(availableB) 
                        "" + fileSizeInB,
                        "" + bytesRead,     // Not currently using. Just for debugging...
                        remainingTimeStr,
                        nlwSpeedStr);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "\n Download - Error: " + e;
        }

        return "";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        int availableB = Integer.parseInt(progress[0]);
        int totalB = Integer.parseInt(progress[1]);
        int percent = (availableB *100)/totalB;   // here we get percentage of download...

        String remainingTime = progress[3];
        String nlwSpeed = progress[4];

        if(remainingTime == null || nlwSpeed == null) return;

        // Now show the details in UI:
        // percent, remainingTime, nlwSpeed...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Code after download completes (UI part)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class? There is a wealth of information in there.

Here is a [Example of TrafficStats](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774)

If you are looking for the maximum download/upload speed for an network interface, well [wget](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/BlqO6eeU3lM) has been ported to Android, so you can use any of these answers

Here is a source code of a small app that measures download speed on edge or 3g 
[Detecting Network Speed and Type on Android (Edge,3G)](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=47)

You can also try following code

```
private SpeedInfo calculate(final long downloadTime, final long bytesIn) {
    SpeedInfo info=new SpeedInfo();
    //from mil to sec
    long bytespersecond   = (bytesIn / downloadTime) * 1000;
    double kilobits = bytespersecond * BYTE_TO_KILOBIT;
    double megabits = kilobits  * KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT;
    info.downspeed = bytespersecond;
    info.kilobits = kilobits;
    info.megabits = megabits;

    return info;
}

private static class SpeedInfo { 
    public double kilobits = 0;
    public double megabits = 0;
    public double downspeed = 0;        
}


private static final int EXPECTED_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1048576; //1MB 1024*1024

private static final double EDGE_THRESHOLD = 176.0;
private static final double BYTE_TO_KILOBIT = 0.0078125;
private static final double KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT = 0.0009765625;
```

Comment: But I've a doubt. Suppose I am downloading a file from a **browser app** and downloading a `xyz.mp4` from my own **another app `abc`** concurrently, then my app need only download speed information of `abc` app only. So will the above given code work here??? Tnx 4 Rply

Comment: How to pass parameters `downloadTime` and `bytesIn` ?? What does it mean ??

Comment: In that case it is not working because this class is in your app not in browser. and downloadtime and bytesIn, you have to calculate from your file.

Comment: So, you mean the speed information is only about downloading task in `abc` only and NOT about downloading in **browser app** ? (Yes/No) This doubt occurred because we are collecting network information from the **Android System** which records information of both app `abc` and **browser**

Comment: no it is not about your abc only. but calculation of of speed depends on native apps.

Comment: OK Got it... But How to get `downloadTime` function parameter of the native app before downloading ??? I want to show it as progress in `ProgressDialog`

Comment: just visit Detecting Network Speed and Type on Android (Edge,3G) as i mention in my link you got what you want.

Comment: Tricky method. OK Got it. No need of `TrafficStats`. Thank you very much

Comment: Once you got the solution then please let me know i want to learn other methods for same.

Comment: Sorry for delay. The solution code given above. Here I'm not using `TrafficStats`

Comment: then what kind of other method you are using? @ChrisJ

Comment: Actual code is complicated. So I simplify the code. If you want, to know, how it works, then go to -> [ProgressDialog with AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15758953/2376893)

Comment: If you are following that answer then your question is worthless. you are asking about to know downloading speed and i cant get any method for same in your above link.

Comment: Code in the above link do not show `download speed` & `remaining time`. So I modified that code using the **SOLUTION** code given above. There is no method(or function). Only using some formula to calculate `download speed` & `remaining time`.