# How to let user download video source for offline view in android?

Tags: android

I have an application to let user to view video directly from my website. How can I create  the sources and give the option for user to view it online or download it for offline view? Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

For your download you will need:

- URLConnection
- InputStream
- OutputStream

It's best if you do it in a new thread (async).

Here's an example: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758953/3218281)

For the save directory, use 'Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()' like in the example.