# How to programmatically get a text file from website in android?

Tags: android, string, file-handling

I am trying to get data from a text file. Assume that the file's path is ***http://mywebsite.com/dir1/dir2/my_file.txt***

Please tell me a way to copy this data to a String or to directly save this file on device.

I have tried other links as well but am unable to find a good solution! Is there anyone who can explain in simple words please?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15758953/892788)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before asking a question, please try to search it first!

Use async task, `call like new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);`

user permission required `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/yourfilename.txt");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }

}
```