# How do I upload/download files (pdf/docx/txt etc.)in localhost from android

Tags: android, file, download, upload

I searched over internet and found tutorials about it .But those were about uploading image files. Is there any tutorial/resources about uploading & downloading all types of files via android(specially pdf,docx) ? it would be really helpful for me if someone give me the answer as my final year project defence upcoming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758856/android-how-to-download-file-from-webserver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733968/4848308