# Gmaps API for downloading Location History (Timeline) Programmatically in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to download location history of mine programmatically in android.

I got this link to download KML file in Browser..

```
https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i7!3i1!2m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8
```

But I need to download programmatically in android.

Comment: Did you find any update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - How to download a file from a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758856/android-how-to-download-a-file-from-a-webserver)