# There is any way to save a music file to be visible to the user, using Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an application to download some music files. How do I save it to the internal storage, to be visible to the user using his file manager?

I searched in all the web, and I found that using the Downloads Manager I can only save files in the internal storage, and using another ways, I couldn't save that in place that the user can see.

I tried all the ways from here: [Android - how to download file from webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758856/android-how-to-download-file-from-webserver), but nothing worked for me...

I expect to save that in a visible place in the internal storage, but I can only save in the external storage, and in the app's dir, which is not visible to the regular user.

Comment: "I found that using the Downloads Manager I can only save files in the internal storage" -- `DownloadManager` downloads to what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Every place that `DownloadManager` downloads to is a location that the user can access. "but nothing worked for me" -- please provide a [mcve] showing what you tried and what your specific symptoms were.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with internal storage. You will need to use external storage instead.

Comment: Thank's,  CommonsWare. I will fix the question tomorrow. (I'm just going to sleep - it's 22:48 in my country now...)